# Please explain how recursion works in this specific example

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I've just started university and have got a python programming class.
I've gotten an assignment where i have to write code which takes a string and splits it into "small letters, this symbol __, and periods" and also "capital letters, spaces and pipes (|)". The code has to be done recursively.

I did write a code that works perfectly, however i did it by trial and error so now I don't know the theory behind the code. Honestly i barely understand recursion at all since we haven't gotten any lectures or explanations.

This is the code i wrote:

```
def split_rec(char_string):


    if not char_string:
        return ("", "")
    
    char = char_string[0]

    first_msg, second_msg = split_rec(char_string[1:])

    if char.islower() or char in "_.":
        return char + first_msg, second_msg
    
    if char.isupper() or char in " |":
        return first_msg, char + second_msg
    
    return first_msg, second_msg
```

I really want to understand how this code works, could anyone explain to me? Line 5 is the one i understand the least.

Comment: You cannot return if you don't have a function to return from.

Comment: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, does any single operation do something you don't expect?  Which specific operation do you need "explained"?  There's nothing particularly special about recursion, the code is simply calling a function like any other.  That function just happens to be the same function.  It executes and returns a value, like any other.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion can be a mind bender for sure. Particularly when a novice. One thing to know is that it is almost always the case that what you can do with recursion you can do with a loop.

The key part here is:

```
char = char_string[0]
first_msg, second_msg = split_rec(char_string[1:])
```

Conceptually, this function picks out the first character of a given string, then pass the rest of the string to be reprocessed by the same function. Note that your method `split_rec()` returns a tuple of two values and those results get stored in `first_msg` and `second_msg` while working though the string and ultimately returned to the initial calling program. You can see from the `if` statements that `char` (the first character of the current substring) get prepended to either the first or second bucket as appropriate.

So, let's take a look with a simple example:

```
split_rec("Hi")
```

In the "root" run we are working with the string `"Hi"` and

```
char = char_string[0]
first_msg, second_msg = split_rec(char_string[1:])
```

sets `char` to `"H"` and `first_msg, second_msg` to whatever is returned from `split_rec("i")`.

We can't go forward in the root call until we know what `split_rec("i")` returns so let's look at that. In this nested call we can see that its `char` is `"i"` and then it goes on to set its `first_msg, second_msg` to whatever is returned from `split_rec("")`.

From the code we know that will `split_rec("")` will `return ("", "")` explicitly and importantly not recall `split_rec()` so our recursion is done and we continue processing the level where we passed in `"i"`.

At this point we have:

```
char = "i"
first_msg = ""   ## <--- returned from split_rec("")
second_msg = ""  ## <--- returned from split_rec("")
```

and the corresponding `if` logic results in this call returning:

`return char + first_msg, second_msg`

i.e.

`return ("i" + "", "")`

So now we know what `split_rec("i")` returns and we can go back to the root call that is working on the full string `split_rec("Hi")`.

That allows us to determine in the root that

```
char = "H"
first_msg = "i"   ## <--- returned from split_rec("i")
second_msg = ""   ## <--- returned from split_rec("i")
```

Again applying the `if` logic we see that the initial call to `split_rec()` will:

```
return first_msg, char + second_msg
```

i.e.

```
return ("i", "H" + "")
```

Ultimately, `print(split_rec("Hi"))` should show us `('i', 'H')`

I hope that helps a bit.